# How to create a matrix using math.js from a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, math.js

Let's say I have a Vector for Variable Y which seems something like this:

`VarY = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0`

And I would like to use math.js to convert it into a Vector of this kind: (so later I can actually use other math.js functions such as Multiply)

```
VarY: [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
```

That is easily done by hardcoding it using `math.matrix([[1],[2],...,[0]])`

But since this vector will be variable, I am looking for a way to make it dynamic...

I was thinking in something like:

```
math.matrix(VarY);
```

But it does not allow variables that way.

EDIT ---

Extra details here:

I am receiving some data as an input, that is what you will see here as "XOriginal"

```
for(var i=0; i<26; i++){
VarY.push([XOriginal[i].splice(26,1)]); // @@@@ HERE I SAVE A COPY FOR ALL THE Y RESULTS OF THE ORIGINAL DATA
XOriginal[i].splice(26,1);
}

for ( i=0; i<26; i++) {
  VarY.push([0]);
}
```

At the end of this, my variable VarY when I use console.log, like this:

```
console.log('VarYReal: ' + VarY);
```

In my console, it appears like this:

```
VarYReal: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Now, since this variable is not storing it as an array or as a matrix, that is the reason why I can not use math.multiply

Comment: Assuming that you actually have `Vary: [1, 2, 3, ...]` you can do `var asArrays = VarY.map(n => [n])`

Comment: @ChrisG That is a good answer to the question, so why is it a comment?

Comment: @ChrisG I am trying that way and it doesn't seem to have any effect, I think it's because it's not in the [] form, I don't know if it has something to do the fact that VarY is a bunch of .push() from an array.

Comment: @RodrigoZazuetaDonnadieu You'll need to be a little more specific about what format your `VarY` is in, because what you've written (`VarY = 1,2,3,...`) isn't valid JavaScript. Including the code (or minimal equivalent) for how VarY is assigned and populated would help, or why exactly it isn't working (what is the result of the `math.matrix(...)`?)

Comment: @Klaycon Ok, I will try to add some more details in an answer so it's easier to read.

Comment: @Klaycon Ok, I will try to add some more details in an answer so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`math.js` has a [`reshape()`](https://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/reshape.html) function. Once you have created a matrix from the original js array, you can use it to change to the matrix you want:

```
const math = require('mathjs')
let y = [0, 1, 2,  3, 4]
let m = math.matrix(y)  

console.log(m.size())     // [ 5 ]

math.reshape(m, [m.size()[0], 1])

console.log(m.size())     // [ 5, 1 ]
console.log(m.valueOf())  // [ [ 0 ], [ 1 ], [ 2 ], [ 3 ], [ 4 ] ]
```

Comment: Im sorry to ask, but... When I try to use math.matrix(VarY) it says Script Error... Does that mean that my VarY is in a format that is not an array? I feel so dumb but i can't find my error.

Comment: @RodrigoZazuetaDonnadieu Please edit the question with the **content of the error** (the fact you simply got an error isn't helpful, but errors are written with messages to tell you what you did wrong!) as well as the declaration of `VarY`, as it's still unclear whether it's an array or some other data structure.

Comment: @Klaycon Finally found my problem, now that I learnt how to use JSON.stringify, i see that the variable `VarY` actually looks like this: `[[[1]],[[2]],[[3]],[[4]],[[5]],[[6]],[[7]],[[8]],[[9]],[[10]],[[11]],[[12]],[[13]],[[14]],[[15]],[[16]],[[17]],[[18]],[[19]],[[20]],[[21]],[[22]],[[23]],[[24]],[[25]],[[26]],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]` So my problem now is how to convert from Prototype into a normal array...